# Entity framework dropping entire database when adding object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework database, with the initializer set to DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges.

Now, I've added a class, named Customer. When starting the app, Entity Framework generates the proper tables and mapping and all is well, but then when i attempt to add something to the table (Customer.Add(anEntity)), Entity Framework prompty deletes every single table in the database, leaving me with only the table containing the model hash, and thus can't insert anything.

Anyone know what can cause such a behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: would you pls provide some code where you have written that add table to entity

Comment: you shouldn't use DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges, maybe when you're starting your dev but after that do not allow your code to change your db schema, it could have disastrous consequences.

Answer (score -1):

As I know, When you add the entity Model in your project, then all mapping and properties class automatically generated. after that you can access the database which you have used with the help of DataContext Class..

Comment: how is it answering the problem ?